Why does memory usage and thread count increase indefinitely with a simple TCP server using react-native-tcp-socket?
I’m using the react-native-tcp-socket package to create a simple TCP server in my React Native app. However, even with the simplest possible server code, memory usage continues to increase indefinitely over time.
The server simply listens for incoming connections, sends an echo message, and closes the socket immediately. Despite not handling or processing any data, memory usage keeps growing until Android OS kills the process and the app closes with no crash or log.
Here is the minimal code I’m using:
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import TcpSocket from 'react-native-tcp-socket';

const TcpServer = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const server = TcpSocket.createServer(function (socket) {
      console.log('Client connected:', socket.address());

      socket.on('data', () => {
        console.log('Received data, but ignoring it.');
        socket.write('Echo server: I got your data');
        socket.end(); // Close connection immediately
      });

      socket.on('error', (error) => {
        console.log('An error occurred with client socket:', error);
        socket.destroy();
      });

      socket.on('close', () => {
        console.log('Closed connection with', socket.address());
      });
    });

    server.listen({ port: 3000, host: '0.0.0.0', reuseAddress: true }, () => {
      console.log('Server is listening on port 3000');
    });

    return () => {
      server.close(() => {
        console.log('Server has been closed');
      });
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>TCP Server is running...</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default TcpServer;


What I've Tried:

Memory management: I’m calling socket.end() to close connections immediately after responding.
Socket handling: I added proper error handling and connection closure logic, but the memory usage keeps increasing.
Device environment: I’ve tested this on both emulator and physical devices, and the issue persists.

Expected Behavior:

Memory usage should remain stable, even as the server accepts and closes connections.

Actual Behavior:

Memory usage increases indefinitely, even though the server does nothing with the received data and closes the connection right away.

Has anyone encountered this issue or found a solution for preventing memory leaks with react-native-tcp-socket?
